# How to resolve java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting an error, while calculating on String,

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; regionStart=5; regionLength=2
```

My implementation is below.

```
private void initializeMyPLsAllotted() { 
    int theMonthWhenICame = Integer.parseInt(myDateHired.substring(5, 7)); //This line is showing the error 
    int theYearWhenICame = Integer.parseInt(myDateHired.substring(0,4)); 
    int theCurrentMonth = Integer.parseInt(todaysDate.substring(5, 7));
    int theCurrentYear = Integer.parseInt(todaysDate.substring(0, 4)); 
    int myTotalMonths = (theCurrentYear - theYearWhenICame)*12 + theCurrentMonth - theMonthWhenICame; 

    if (myTotalMonths > 6) {
        numberOfPLsAllotted = 2;
    } else {
        numberOfPLsAllotted = 0;
    }

    myPLs = numberOfPLsAllotted;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the value of MyDateHired?

Comment: String todaysDate/* <== FROM SERVER   */, myDateHired, theMonthLabel, theMonthFileLabel;

Comment: the variable MyDateHired is not in the format or length you are expecting.
you cannot get a substring of indexes 5 to 7 when the length of MyDateHired is 4

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; regionStart=5; regionLength=2

it clearly says that length of your string is 4 and you are trying to fetch sub-string from index 5. make sure your string is valid

you can check something like that to avoid crashing your app

```
private void initializeMyPLsAllotted() { 
    if(myDateHired.length() > 7 && todaysDate.length() > 7){
        int theMonthWhenICame = Integer.parseInt(myDateHired.substring(5, 7));
        int theYearWhenICame = Integer.parseInt(myDateHired.substring(0,4)); 
        int theCurrentMonth = Integer.parseInt(todaysDate.substring(5, 7));
        int theCurrentYear = Integer.parseInt(todaysDate.substring(0, 4)); 
        int myTotalMonths = (theCurrentYear - theYearWhenICame)*12 + theCurrentMonth - theMonthWhenICame; 
        if(myTotalMonths>6) {
            numberOfPLsAllotted = 2;
        } else {
            numberOfPLsAllotted = 0;
        }
        myPLs = numberOfPLsAllotted;
    } else {
        // print some error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that the section you're trying to `substring` is outside of the string length.

### Example

```
String test = "123";
String testSubstringOne = test.substring(0, 1);
//testSubstringOne -> "1"

String testSubstringTwo = test.substring(0, 5);
//testSubstringTwo -> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Make sure your `myDateHired` has the value you expect.

### Tip from the coach

You say that those values are from a server... Maybe you should look into returning data in a more friendly format such as json.

Answer (score 0):

As [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) says, the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be throwed when：

> if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length
>   of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex

so check `myDateHired` before using it.